# can someone explain me what my mission in better way please ( ESP8266 module )

Tags: arduino

.  Your mission is to write a simple "Math Quiz Show" program that asks the user to input the sum of two numbers supplied by the microprocessor and lights an LED if the answer is correct.

Initialize three integer variables: x, y and z.
Open a connection with the serial port using the appropriate Serial function.
Print "Enter the sum of [x] and [y]:  " to the serial monitor, where x and y are random numbers between 0 and 9 supplied by the microprocessor.  See Arduino reference for random() function.
Use the script in Section 4.3 to read a sequence of numbers supplied by the user and convert the sequence to a numerical value. Store this value in z.
Use an IF statement to compare the user's input to the correct answer.
Light an LED for 3 seconds if the answer is correct, then ask another question.  Use the same LED1 pin from lesson P1.

Comment: What would better look like?  What is not clear?  Is there a professor you should ask?

Comment: The explanation seems fine the way it is.  It even provides you with the reference for the Random() function and a sample script in 4.3 and a hint about the IF statement.  Maybe you could actually try to come up with an answer and post what you come up with, if you need more help

Answer (score 1):

They just want you to check if the user can do simple addition.

You have to display this question on the screen,

> "Enter the sum of [x] and [y]: "

where both x and y are generated randomly by the microprocessor.

Then you allow the user to type an answer, if he types the correct answer you have to light the LED for 3 seconds before asking for an other addition. Nothing is specified in case he answers wrong.